# cannot be resolved to a type error in unit test

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

I have a relatively simple unit test for testing a static method within my java application.

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void testGetWeightedGradeWithWeightSumLessThan100(){   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeOne = Pair.of(10, 80.00);   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeTwo = Pair.of(25, 90);
   @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
   double weightedGrade = GradeUtils.getWeightedGrade(gradeOne, gradeTwo);
}
```

This works perfectly fine and my test passes as expected. However, I do not need to assign the output of `getWeightedGrade` to a variable, since I am expecting an exception to be thrown when the method runs. So, I tried to update the unit test as follows:

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void testGetWeightedGradeWithWeightSumLessThan100(){   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeOne = Pair.of(10, 80.00);   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeTwo = Pair.of(25, 90);
   @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
   GradeUtils.getWeightedGrade(gradeOne, gradeTwo);
}
```

This causes a compiler error:

```
GradeUtils.getWeightedGrade cannot be resolved to a type.
```

When I move the suppressWarnings annotation outside of the method body, it compiles fine.

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
public void testGetWeightedGradeWithWeightSumLessThan100(){   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeOne = Pair.of(10, 80.00);   
   Pair<Integer, Double> gradeTwo = Pair.of(25, 90);
   GradeUtils.getWeightedGrade(gradeOne, gradeTwo);
}
```

This isn't a big deal, I'm just curious as to why it doesn't compile when I remove the variable declaration.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add declaration of `GradeUtils.getWeightedGrade` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) that the `@SurpressWarnings` flag only works on

- Type
- Field
- Method
- Parameter
- Constructor
- Local_variable

But *without* the `double weightedGrade = ...` you are trying to use it on a *method-call*, which isn't a valid target.

The reason it works for the double declaration is because it is a local variable. And it works before the method declaration because it is also a valid target.